# Ubuntu 12.04 u fails black screen after install

Tags: 12.04, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a USB for dual boot with windows 7. Windows is working fine but Ubuntu failed to boot after restart. When I select to start ubuntu it loads a black screen with command prompt.
Please Help I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

in the grub loader ( at boot time ) :

you get an option for windows 7, Ubuntu , generic ubuntu , etc..

select the option "ubuntu".

If it fails to load the os it will print something on the screen.. Like :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

?????>
```

Please copy that and put it here.. Will be helpful in determining what might be going wrong..